# Regular Expression requiring a fix

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

So i was experimenting with an apache rewrite rule
to redirect from

`/en-in/holidays/destinations/xyz-packages`

to

`/en-in/holidays/destinations/about-xyz/xyz-packages`

Here is rewrite rule which i made

```
RewriteRule ^/en-in/holidays/destinations/(.*)-packages /en-in/holidays/destinations/about-$1/$1-packages [R=301,L]
```

Correct me if i am wrong , i am under the impression that $1 would be the captured string of `(.*)`

But the rewrite rule isn't behaving as its supposed to be.

Could someone please let me know , where am i making the mistake ?

P.S : i am pretty new to this

Comment: Yes, you are right `$1` is the match of your first regex capture group `(.*)` but **What exactly is your problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start your pattern/substitution with a '/'. Remove that and it will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en-in/holidays/destinations/(.*)-packages en-in/holidays/destinations/about-$1/$1-packages [R=301,L]
```

You could also just add a ? after the / to make it an optional match:

```
RewriteRule ^/?en-in/...
```